# Expand a panel over other in tmux

Tags: tmux

How to move panel in order to go from

```
+---+    +---+
|1|2|    |1| |
+---+ to +-+2|
| 3 |    |3| |
+---+    +---+
```

Is there a binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no existing binding for that but you can achive this by `breake-pane` and `join-pane`

```
tmux break-pane -s :.3
tmux join-pane -t :!.1 -d
```

Or in command mode

```
break-pane -s :.3
join-pane -t :!.1 -d
```

Also there is `prefix-Space` binding for choosing next-layout